# Trying to return a value of 0 or 1 into text using if and else function

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo `<?php echo $two['appeal_state']?>` but the value for the table is 1 or 0. I want to echo the text "open" if value = 1 end else the value = 0 is "closed". I can't seem to do it (I'm kind of new to PHP)

```
<form>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username:</th> 
        <th>Reason:</th> 
        <th>Banned by:</th>  
        <th>Appeal State:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="success">
        <td><?php echo $two['value']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $two['reason']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $two['added_by']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $two['appeal_state'] ?>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (something) echo 'something' else echo 'something else'`

Comment: Use a simple if statement: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php or the ternary operator (short hand if statement): http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary But you probably really want to read a basic PHP tutorial which will cover that.

Comment: `if`, `else`, `echo` - you already mentioned everything you need to know *in* your question.. you should try reading some tutorials, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple task. You just need to use ternary or `if...else` statement:

```
<?php echo ($two['appeal_state'] == 0) ? "closed" : "open"; ?>
```

Or you can also go for the detailed `if` and `else` statement.

```
<?php
  if ($two['appeal_state'] == 0)
    echo "closed";
  else
    echo "open";
?>
```

See more about ternary operators here:

- [PHP Shorthand If/Else Using Ternary Operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)
- [How to use the PHP ternary operator](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator)

Comment: This is interesting, if I wanted to do more research on this what should I look for?

Comment: @Jashun Learn the basics of PHP. `;)` I have also given you the links too.

Comment: Google the words 'php tutorial'. That's where to look.

Comment: This topic is covered in basic switching and branching of code and conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that:

```
<?php echo ($two['appeal_state'] == 1)? "open" : "close" ?>
```

This is a reduced 'if else' statement, where the first item ("open"), is when the conditional is true and the second item ("close") is when the conditional is false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code :

```
<form>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Username:</th> 
 <th>Reason:</th> 
 <th>Banned by:</th>  
 <th>Appeal State:</th>  
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="success">
  <td><?php echo $two['value']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $two['reason']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $two['added_by']; ?></td>
    <td><?php
  if ($two['appeal_state'] == 0)
    echo "closed";
  else
    echo "open";
?>
    </td>
    <td></td>
      </tr>
```